# Merge Dataframes with Repeated Rows

Tags: r

I have rather large datasets of metabolite data. Some sets have repetition that is unlabeled (no column indicating repetition). A small example is below.

```
a<-structure(list(ABBRC = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
        ), .Label = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "factor"), X = 1:7, 
            Y = 1:7, Year = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
            2009L)), .Names = c("ABBRC", "X", "Y", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -7L))
        b<-structure(list(ABBRC = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
        ), .Label = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "factor"), Z = c(1L, 
        2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), A = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Year = c(2009L, 
        2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L)), .Names = c("ABBRC", 
        "Z", "A", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
        ))
    merge(a,b)
ABBRC Year X Y Z A
1     X1 2009 1 1 1 1
2     X2 2009 2 2 2 2
3     X2 2009 3 3 2 2
4     X3 2009 4 4 4 4
5     X4 2009 5 5 5 5
6     X4 2009 5 5 6 6
7     X4 2009 5 5 7 7
8     X4 2009 5 5 8 8
9     X4 2009 6 6 5 5
10    X4 2009 6 6 6 6
11    X4 2009 6 6 7 7
12    X4 2009 6 6 8 8
13    X4 2009 7 7 5 5
14    X4 2009 7 7 6 6
15    X4 2009 7 7 7 7
16    X4 2009 7 7 8 8
```

When I merge, combinations of repeated rows are output. This is the expected behavior, but it's not what I would like. I would like for the data to be merged as if they were repetitions (they are). 
Is there a function to do this sort of merge, or is it easier to label repetitions and then merge? If it's easier to label, what's a good way of doing it?

Desired Output

```
structure(list(ABBRC = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "factor"), X = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, NA), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
NA), Z = c(1L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), A = c(1L, 2L, NA, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Year = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L)), .Names = c("ABBRC", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", 
"Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
ABBRC  X  Y  Z  A Year
1    X1  1  1  1  1 2009
2    X2  2  2  2  2 2009
3    X2  3  3 NA NA 2009
4    X3  4  4  4  4 2009
5    X4  5  5  5  5 2009
6    X4  6  6  6  6 2009
7    X4  7  7  7  7 2009
8    X4 NA NA  8  8 2009
```

Comment: I'm having trouble groking what behavior you are after. You're implicitly merging on `Year` and `ABBRC`. Is that what you want? Which fields have to match in order for you to consider the row a "duplicate".

Comment: JD, Year is unnecessary in this example, but I will be merging many datasets from different years. Essentially, what I want is in the above edit. I don't mind having an extra column of repetition IDs, but I'm not sure how to get there without a series of confusing loops.

Answer (score 2):

After deleting my first painful attempt, here's another method, but not as good as your own `plyr` approach. It involves first generating a dummy `time` variable.

```
a$time <- as.numeric(ave(as.character(a$ABBRC), a$ABBRC, a$Year, FUN=seq_along))
b$time <- as.numeric(ave(as.character(b$ABBRC), b$ABBRC, b$Year, FUN=seq_along))
library(reshape2)
ab.long <- rbind(melt(a, id.vars=c("ABBRC", "Year", "time")),
                 melt(b, id.vars=c("ABBRC", "Year", "time")))
dcast(ab.long, ABBRC + Year + time ~ variable)
#   ABBRC Year time  X  Y  Z  A
# 1    X1 2009    1  1  1  1  1
# 2    X2 2009    1  2  2  2  2
# 3    X2 2009    2  3  3 NA NA
# 4    X3 2009    1  4  4  4  4
# 5    X4 2009    1  5  5  5  5
# 6    X4 2009    2  6  6  6  6
# 7    X4 2009    3  7  7  7  7
# 8    X4 2009    4 NA NA  8  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's cool to answer your own question, but I figured out how to do it by creating an index variable. Thanks to Hadley for some advice on plyr/seq_along().

```
require(plyr)
a<-ddply(a, .(ABBRC), transform, rep=seq_along(ABBRC))
b<-ddply(b, .(ABBRC), transform, rep=seq_along(ABBRC))
merge(a,b, all=T)

  ABBRC Year rep  X  Y  Z  A
1    X1 2009   1  1  1  1  1
2    X2 2009   1  2  2  2  2
3    X2 2009   2  3  3 NA NA
4    X3 2009   1  4  4  4  4
5    X4 2009   1  5  5  5  5
6    X4 2009   2  6  6  6  6
7    X4 2009   3  7  7  7  7
8    X4 2009   4 NA NA  8  8
```

Comment: +1 -- It's totally cool to answer your own questions here. The same approach occurred to me after I had posted my original overly complicated answer, but I ended up using `dcast`. If you have multiple years, shouldn't your index variable be a combination of "ABBRC" and "Year"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this problem. One method is to identify the duplicates prior to merging

```
merge(a, b[!duplicatesFromA, ])
#    ABBRC Year X Y Z A
#  1    X4 2009 5 5 8 8
#  2    X4 2009 6 6 8 8
#  3    X4 2009 7 7 8 8
```

And there are of course several ways to find the duplicates.
Here is one that uses colSums of nested apply loops.

```
duplicatesFromA <- 
    colSums(apply(b, 1, function(row.b) {
        apply(a, 1, function(row.a) {
            all(row.b==row.a)
        })
    })) > 0
```